# Why these code doesn't work as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I write a controlloer

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @notification = current_user.notification
    if @notification.unread == 0
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @notification.unread == 0
      @notification.save
    end
  end
end
```

And i expect  `@notification.unread` be 0 after show index page.But it can't work actually.
How to change these code to make it work correctly.

Hope you can help me and thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do but you're calling == twice, this is a comparison operator, I think in the second section you are want to set the value, so you should use = only

Like this

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @notification = current_user.notification
    if @notification.unread == 0
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @notification.unread = 0
      @notification.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `@notification.unread = 0` instead of `@notification.unread == 0`

Comment: Oh, i made such a ssily mistake.  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
   else
      @notification.unread = 0
      @notification.save
    end
```

@notification.unread == 0 will not change value of attribute. :)

Answer (score 0):

its always a good idea to move the business logic to models, so you could write this as

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base

  def unread?
    unread == 0
  end

end

class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @notification = current_user.notification
    @notification.unread? ? (@notification.update_attributes("unread", 0) : (redirect_to root_path))
  end
end
```